# Confusion on C++ return reference from function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been having some confusion on the reference in C++, so I did a little experiment with the following function

```
std::vector<float> & fun(std::vector<float> & x) {
    return x;
}
```

Then I call the function using the following two ways:

```
std::vector<float> x(10000);
std::vector<float> result1 = fun(x);
std::vector<float> & result2 = fun(x);
```

Now the variable result2 is indeed a reference of x, but result1 seems to be a copy of x instead of a reference. So here I am confused:

Why can I declare a non-reference variable to be the return value of a function that returns a reference?

Does C++ changes my returned reference to a non-reference variable because my declaration of result1 is not a reference?

Comment: Because the assignment operator, like the copy constructor, for `std::vector` accepts a (`const`) reference.    That operator does a deep copy.

Comment: I think in this case it is the copy ctor that invoked, not the assigment operator. 
assigment is only between already existing objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `fun(x)` simply accepts a reference to `x` and returns it, your code (on the left) is equivalent to the code on the right:

```
a std::vector<float> x(10000);          a std::vector<float> x(10000);

std::vector<float> result1 = fun(x);    std::vector<float> result1 = x;
std::vector<float> &result2 = fun(x);   std::vector<float> &result2 = x;
```

In other words, `result1` becomes a *copy* of `x`, while `result2` becomes a *reference* to `x`. That means `result1` is distinct from `x`, while `result2` and `x` refer to the same underlying data.

It's really no different to:

```
int a = 42;
int b = a;
int &c = a;
```

At that point, `b` is an independent copy that, if changed, will not affect the other two variables. However, since `a` and `c` refer to the same underlying data, changing one will affect the other.

Answer (score 5):

That's basically the same as

```
std::vector<float> x(10000);
std::vector<float> & result2 = x;
std::vector<float> result1 = result2;
```

The language allows it since `result2` is a reference of `x`, each mention of `result2` is the same as `x`. You could see the reference as being an *alias*, `result2` is an *alias* of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real *change* happening.

What happens is that a reference refers to something, and when you use the reference in an expression, you (usually) get what it refers to. So, if I have something like:

```
int x = 1;
int &rx = x;

std::cout << rx;
```

What gets printed out is the value of `x`--the reference gets dereferenced to get the value, and that's what gets printed out. Likewise, if I had something like:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int rx = x;
int ry = y;
int z = rx + ry;
```

...the compiler is going to dereference `rx` and `ry` to get the values of `x` and `y`. Then it adds those together, and assigns the result to `z`.

#### Summary

A reference is an alias for some object. Under most circumstances (essentially anything other than initializing another reference) using the reference in an expression uses the object that the reference refers to, not the reference itself.